# Firefox max-width not working in nested div

Tags: css

So I have an issue that appears on Firefox.
Basically I have a container with set width (let's say 300px).

Inside it nested a couple of levels is a component that uses truncation to hide text with max-width. CSS rule would look like this for example:

```
max-width: calc( ((100vw - 376px) / 12) * 8 + 168px );
```

Child span uses basic line-clamp + overflow technique for hiding extra content.

What I found out is that this code constrains width of elements of component and truncation works fine on Chrome but it doesn't work as expected in Firefox. I guess that it makes sense since this calculation uses vw for setting max-width but it confuses me why it works on Chrome. Does Firefox somehow differently do calculations?

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
}

.max-width__component {
  /* This is probably calculated to be a bigger value than width 
  of container */
  max-width: calc( ((100vw - 376px) / 12) * 8 + 168px);
}

.truncation {
  display: -webkit-box;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="max-width__component">
    <span class="truncation">
          Some dummy content that is normally longer and truncated
        </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post a simplified example to show the issue. You can just use a fixed width for max width to make it easier

Comment: I would be avoiding this whole math rigmarole with a modern layout strategy (flexbox, grid) and an absolutely-positioned inner box. I'd work that up but I'm not clear on your goals. See if you can get the snippet showing the problem.

Comment: On mac firefox, I tested this with `line-clamp: 1` and it works fine. Add more text so the truncation actually works. I also tried adding more text with line clamp at 2 and it works too

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue - it looks the same like in chrome...

Comment: You are right guys, I added an answer with more detailed codepen. Anyways, I fixed my issue by using flex-shrink. Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem indeed wasn't with setting max-width

One thing that was missing from my code snippet was another child element that represents icons (https://codepen.io/Skafec/pen/yLbNBJM) but the issue still wasn't reproduced in this codepen.

How I fixed is that I added:

```
flex-shrink: 0;
```

on icon wrapper which makes sure that icon always takes the same space and doesn't get pushed outside of the main container.